# Master and Content Pages VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

I created a master page using visual studio. I'm trying to add content my pages but I'm having an issue. It's probably a simple thing that I'm missing.

My master page has a few divs. Basically a Header, a Sub Header, a left column with a menu, a Footer and then the bulk of the page is my Main.

My example video shows the instructor just dragging an image over to the body of the content page (in design view) and it works. She also dragged a gridview and a couple other items.

This part is annoying me because it's hanging me up.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I created several divs. When I did this my content placeholder shifted all the way down to the bottom, which is why my content was placed on the bottom.

I fixed my code so that way I had something like this.

```
<div id="Main">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

which fixed it. You need those lines  and the  in order to place the content in the main.

I am happy I found my problem.

JWV